# Writing an Order Notification Class Python

Tags: python, events

I have this simple class that supposed to handle people making online orders and picking them in store. The DeliveryDispatch class has a background task that brings in orders and places them on a "shelf".

As customers walk in and try to get their order, the order is either there and they can walk out, or they will wait till an event is set.

I was hoping to see if there are other elegant ways to solve this problem:

I was also thinking of retrieve order, taking in a time the customer is willing to wait before heading out.

Would this also be threadsafe if the customers all came in in parallel ?

```py
import threading
import time

class DeliveryDispatch:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.orders = {}
        self.wait_q = {}
        self.running = True
        background_getter = threading.Thread(target = self._run, daemon=True)
        background_getter.start()
        self.order_lock = threading.Lock()
        
    
    def run(self) -> None:
        while self.running:
            order = get_order()
            with self.order_lock:
                self.orders[order.customer_id] = order.item
                if order.customer_id in self.wait_q:
                    e = self.wait_q.pop(order.customer_id)
                    e.set()
            time.sleep(5)
    
    def retrieve_order(self, customer_id) -> Any:
        with self.order_lock:
            if customer_id in self.orders:
                return self.orders[customer_id]
            else:
                event = threading.Event()
                self.wait_q[customer_id] = event
        event.wait()
        return self.orders[customer_id]
    

def main():
    delivery = DeliveryDispatch()
    c1 = delivery.retrieve_order(1)
    c2 = delivery.retrieve_order(2)
    c3 = delivery.retrieve_order(3)
```